# How to create Paypal Developer Account (not sandbox)

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to create a Paypal developer account from [here](https://developer.paypal.com/classic-home/) (https://developer.paypal.com/classic-home/) and then clicking on `Login into Dashboard` and `SignUp` and it keeps giving me this error:

> Something went wrong on our end. Please try again.

[image]

I used my real domain and password like below but I am always getting this message!

Comment: Is there a reason you need a *developer.paypal-specific* account? You can log in with any live www.paypal.com account , and might have better luck creating one over there